# Proper name for an intermediate table between others two intermediate

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, naming-conventions

I have 4 entities: `Event`, `Message`, `Flow` and `Document`.

`Event` table stores a limited (seeded) number of records. `Message` has many events and each event can be related to many messages. The name `event_message` was given for the intermediate table.

As you can see, the convention for intermediate tables are: `{tablename}_{tablename}`.

`Flow` table stores a limited (seeded) number of records. `Message` has many flows and each flow can be related to many messages. The name `flow_message` was given for the intermediate table.

A document is created on each relation between `Flow` and `Message` (each record on `flow_message`).

**The issue starts here:**

Each event on a message has different documents by flow. It means: for each new record on intermediate table `flow_message`, each record on intermediate `event_message` has a new document related.

To solve this, I created an intermediate table between `event_message` and `flow_message` named: `event_message_flow_message`.

[image]

Is this correct (in some conventional way)? Is this modeling correct?

How to proper model and naming the intermediate table derivative by two others intermediate tables?

Answer (score 1):

I also wish there was some convention. Since I do not know any official convention, I invented mine. The important thing is to respect the convention you choose.

So I would change the `event_message_flow_message` to `rel_eventmessage_flowmessage`.
But for me your convention is pretty nice.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to make a recommendation because your model seems a bit odd to me.  You have 1:1 relationships between both `DOCUMENT` and `FLOW_MESSAGE` and `DOCUMENT` and `EVENT_MESSAGE_FLOW_MESSAGE`.  It's hard to reconcile this in my mind with the many to one relationships to `EVENT_MESSAGE_FLOW_MESSAGE`.  If you're relationships to `DOCUMENT` are really 1:1 (mandatory), then why keep documents in a separate table?

To address your question about table naming: I would argue that the {table}_{table} convention for naming intersection tables is not a best practice but rather a fallback for cases where you can't think of a better name.

The best practice is for **names of tables to reflect the business name** of the thing which is recorded / described by the data in the table.  It's not always possible to do this, especially for intersection tables.  Intersection tables represent many-to-many relationships, and relationships are often difficult to describe with a noun.

In your case, I don't think that your convention is actually making things especially easy to understand.  I'd probably try to simplify with something like `MESSAGE_DOCUMENT` or even just `DOCUMENT` - since these seem to be 1:1 related in any case.